# Trying to change session.name in htaccess, remains as PHPSESSID

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I've put the following into an .htaccess file:

```
php_value session_name SSOSESSID
```

Just to confirm, the .htaccess is being picked up (I tested with a simple redirect, and it worked ok) and in the virtual host apache config file AllowOverride is set to All. So this part seems fine.

Anyway I can also confirm I've restarted apache but when I check the phpinfo() output the session.name is still PHPSESSID.

Is there anything else I've missed out here? Thanks

Comment: I think this setting is in the php.ini, not htaccess. http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.name

Comment: Yes but PHP settings can be set in .htaccess, do you mean this particular setting cannot be set in htaccess?
http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php

Comment: I've never put PHP configuration settings in the .htaccess file. So I can't say one way or another on that. I'd imagine having configurations in multiple files could be confusing for future developers though.

Comment: @chris85: _“I think this setting is in the php.ini, not htaccess”_ – the very page you linked to says this setting is changeable PHP_INI_ALL (and what that means you find here: http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php)

Comment: Normally I wouldn't put PHP config in htaccess, but in this case I only want to set it for this app.. not every app on the server. So either it can go in PHP code or htaccess seemed like possible options. Anyway it was a fair question to ask, Apache does provide this functionality for certain cases. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with below line in your .htaccess :

```
php_value session.name "SSOSESSID"
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can change the default name in htaccess as well as ini file in php just using php_value session.name "myStuff"

Comment: To make your answer a good one, please provide examples of both.